# SQL Dynamic Query Error ( Column name invalid for a value that isn't a column name )

Tags: sql

Dynamic query throwing error saying invalid column name 'Headquarters'. Not sure why it would throw that error. If I take out the where statement at the end of With block it runs fine so I think it is breaking there. Please help. I have already tried restarting everything and refreshing the cache. Don't see any errors where I am using " instead of '.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '10/25/2021';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE;
DECLARE @DynamicQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ColumnList AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @LocationNameFromApp AS VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @SDstr as NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @EDstr as NVARCHAR(10);

Set @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY,13,@StartDate);
SET @SDstr = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @StartDate, 120);
SET @EDstr = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @EndDate, 120);
SET @LocationNameFromApp = 'Headquarters';

-- populate column list 
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,DateData)
    FROM DateRange 
    WHERE DateData < @EndDate
)
SELECT @ColumnList = ISNULL(@ColumnList + ',', '')
        + QUOTENAME(FORMAT(DateData, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
FROM DateRange
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 300);


set @DynamicQuery = '

WITH Schedule AS (
    SELECT
        P.PositionName,
        S.ShiftName,
        U.FirstName,
        U.LastName,
        R.RotationName,
        D.FullDateUSA,
        L.LocationName
    FROM
        dbo.factSchedule F
        INNER JOIN dbo.Users U on F.UserID = U.UserID
        INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate D on F.KeyDate = D.DateKey
        INNER JOIN dbo.Positions P on F.PositionID = P.PositionID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Shifts S on F.ShiftID = S.ShiftID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Rotations R on F.RotationID = R.RotationID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Locations L on F.LocationID = L.LocationID
    WHERE LocationName='+@LocationNameFromApp+' AND FullDateUSA >= '+@SDstr+' AND FullDateUSA <= '+@EDstr+'
)

SELECT * INTO dbo.'+@LocationNameFromApp+'SchedDays
FROM Schedule
    PIVOT (MAX(ShiftName) FOR FullDateUSA IN ('+@ColumnList+')) P  
    
ALTER TABLE dbo.'+@LocationNameFromApp+'SchedDays ADD ID int identity(1,1) not null

ALTER TABLE dbo.'+@LocationNameFromApp+'SchedDays ADD CONSTRAINT '+@LocationNameFromApp+'pk_ID primary key(ID)

    '
execute (@DynamicQuery)

;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this is the line that is breaking the query. WHERE LocationName='+@LocationNameFromApp+' AND FullDateUSA >= '+@SDstr+' AND FullDateUSA <= '+@EDstr+'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming because you are setting it as a constant here -

```
SET @LocationNameFromApp = 'Headquarters';
```

dynamic query translates it as `LocationName=Headquarters` instead of `LocationName='Headquarters'`.

Try and change the setting of the variable as below -

```
SET @LocationNameFromApp = '''Headquarters''';
```

so it will be translated to `LocationName='Headquarters'`.

Comment: or you can change the dynamic query too
LocationName='''+@LocationNameFromApp+'''

print the DynamicQuery before executing you will know the error.